# prepopulate form from a hook within wordpress function.php file

Tags: hooks, forms

I have a form that I created by simply using the HTML editor in the wp-admin backend for a page. I have some variables in a hook for that page, I would like to pre-populate some of the form fields with the variables in the hook.

```
add_action('wp', 'simple_form');

function simple_form(){
    $firstname = 'Bob';
    //Do something to populate the form field name <fname> with "Bob"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare the variable `global` *before* using it.

```
function simple_form(){
    global $firstname;
    $firstname = 'Bob';
    //Do something to populate the form field name <fname> with "Bob"
}
```

Your form should be able to do ...

```
global $firstname;
echo $firstname;
```

... to use the variable.

However, I can't help but think there is a better way to do this.

1. Setting a `global` is best avoided if you can
2. and doing what you are doing-- hooking to `wp`-- you are going to populate these variable for every page on the site-- both front and back end-- every time a page loads. That is a waste of resources. There are many, many other hooks and I am pretty sure that one of them would work much better than `wp`.

Without having more details about your project I don't think I can do better than generalities but [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/99003/edit) your question and I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to predefine some variables in an earlier hook/action and use this vars in a later hook/action.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'predefine_my_vars' );
function predefine_my_vars() {
  global $my_vars;
  $my_vars = array(
    'name' => 'Bob',
  );
}

add_action( 'wp_footer' 'show_my_vars' );
function show_my_vars() {
  global $my_vars;
  if ( isset( $my_vars['name'] ) )
    echo "Hello {$my_vars['name']}!";
}
```

The `global` keyword is one method to make a var in another function accessible. But it is not the best way. The global namespace is very full and WordPress uses a lot of vars. You need a really unique name for your vars.

Another way is to use a session. A session is normally not made to make a var global accessible, but you can 'missuse' it for that.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'predefine_my_vars' );
function predefine_my_vars() {
 // start a session if no one was started
 $session_id = session_id();
 if ( empty( $session_id ) )
   session_start();

  $my_vars = array(
    'name' => 'Bob',
  );

  $_SESSION['my_vars'] = serialize( $my_vars );
}

add_action( 'wp_footer' 'show_my_vars' );
function show_my_vars() {
  $session_id = session_id();
  // no session was started
  if ( empty( $session_id ) )
    return false;
  else
    $my_vars = ( isset( $_SESSION['my_vars'] ) ) ? unserialize( $_SESSION['my_vars'] ) : array();

  if( isset( $my_vras['name'] ) )
    echo "Hello {$my_vars['name']}!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass the data to the action, right

hope this code helps you

```
$data = 'my data is Here';
add_action('wp', function() use ($data) {

echo $data;

});
```